# CSS for semi transparent content area over an image, similar to lightbox

Tags: html, css

I need some css to display a semi transparent box over an image which I will display non transparent text or other content over, similar to how the lightbox style text descriptions work.

I ended up coming up with the following css:

```
.widgetTitle 
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}


.widgetContent
{
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 310px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: url(../images/white.png) repeat;    
}

.widgetContent h4
{
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: #ED1666;
}

.widgetContent p
{
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 315px;
}
```

And then the items are displayed as follows:

```
<div class="panel">
    <a href="some-link">
        <img src="/images/image.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
        <div class="widgetContent">
           <h4>Some Heading</h4>
           <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Seems to work ok

Comment: What you tried so far? This is not a "gimme the codes" site. Show what you've attempted, and we'll try to help fix it. But at least show you've put **SOME** effort into this.

Comment: And if you throw it up on jsfiddle.net, that'll make it easier for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

Comment: rgba support is still limited

Comment: That's true, I updated my answer for a wider range of compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The easier and most supported way of doing this would be to create a semi transparent gif tile, and put it as the `background-image` on the div.

```
background:url(/path/to/image.gif) repeat transparent top left
```

Comment: Wouldn't a png be better? The only real exception to using png's is IE6. In that case, he can use the DXImage filter and get the same result. The only reason I say png is because it gives you true alpha transparency, whereas the gif only gives you index transparency.

Comment: I would probably use a png for that reason but a gif works across the board because you will just need it to be a square

Comment: I never really tried it with a gif. I may have to try it out of curiosity.